# Boot hangs with errors: USB device not accepting address, device descriptor read/64, error, unable to enumerate USB device

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu

During Xubuntu 22.04 boot, it hangs with the following messages:

```
usb 2-9: device not accepting address 4, error -62
usb 2-9: device descriptor read/64, error -62
usb usb2-por9: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The first two messages are repeated several times, then the boot freezes.

When I boot in recovery I see the same messages but the boot completes OK.

How can I achieve a normal boot?

This is an older machine. In BIOS I cannot disable specific USB ports.
This port is now free of devices although the devices work well once booted into recovery.

Comment: To be clear it works ok if no device is in the USB port? The message is pretty clear a defective USB device but it could be the USB port in the as you say older computer.

Comment: No, the boot hangs regardless of the device. But if the device is connected it works (in recovery mode). Probably the USB device is defective, but the problem is a software one - how to ignore this (non critical) error to complete the boot, as the recovery mode is able to do.